# How to get environment value from variable?

Tags: bash, environment

If I have a var which value will be HOME, PATH or My_Var etc, how can I get $HOME, $PATH from the var?

some thing like below:

```
VAR="HOME"
echo ${$VAR} # does not work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*As simple as that:*

```
VAR="HOME"
echo ${!VAR}
```

*[More on indirect references](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html)*